# Instance UserControl in Windows Forms from another class library when click button

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a main project, which has a panel and menu. When the user clicks the button, I want to load a user control.

I created the class library for UI. But when I click the button it does not load the user control in the main project. What is the problem?

Main project :

```
private void BtnMainPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (!PanelHome.Controls.Contains(Home.Instance))
        {
            PanelHome.Controls.Add(Home.Instance);
            Home.Instance.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            Home.Instance.BringToFront();
        }
        else
        {
            Home.Instance.BringToFront();
        }
}
```

UI :

```
public partial class Home : UserControl
{
    #region Variable
    public static Home Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return Singleton<Home>.GetInstance();
        }
    }
    #endregion

    public Home()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MessageBox.Show("Load");
    }
}
```

Singleton :

```
public sealed class Singleton<T> where T : class, new()
{
    private volatile static T Instance;
    private static object _lock = new object();

    public static T GetInstance()
    {
        if (Instance == null)
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                if (Instance == null)
                {
                    Instance = new T();
                }
            }
        }
        return Instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: why does it have to be a singleton?  That's strange for a user control.

Comment: You [already posted this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48040931/not-load-user-controle-in-homepanel-from-other-project#comment83054074_48040931).  Please don't abuse the system with multiple user accounts.  And don't abuse our free time, we have a strict ["be nice" policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) here.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void FrmDashboard_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = DAl.GetTables();
    DataTable dt1;

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            o = new Available();
            if (dt.Rows[i]["Status"].ToString() == "A         ")
            {`enter code here`
                o.lblTable.BackColor = Color.DarkSeaGreen;
            }
            if (dt.Rows[i]["Status"].ToString() == "B         ")
            {
                o.lblTable.BackColor = Color.DarkRed;
            }
            else if (dt.Rows[i]["Status"].ToString() == "C         ")
            {
                o.lblTable.BackColor = Color.Blue;
            }
            o.ButtonClick1 +=new Available.EventHandler(o_ButtonClick1);       
            // MessageBox.Show(o.vButton1.Tag.ToString());
            o.lblTable.Text = i + "";
             panel.Controls.Add(o);
        }
    }   
}

protected void o_ButtonClick1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show(o.lblTable.Text);
}
```